# HowTo serve dynamic data in xml from python

Tags: python, xml, web-services, http

I have got a program that collects data from various sources and builds an excerpt in XML.

It would be easy to write that data to a file and then let apache do the work, but I do not want to depend on a webserver, because it is only one dynamic set of XML.

The result should be displayed in a browser, with automatic self refresh.

What I want is - how do I serve data to a browser without creating a file in the file system, but dynamically from python.

The SimpleHTTPserver does not fit.

What I've accomplished so far is - telnet to port and output XML or Text, but the browser interprets it as Text - not html and not xml

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: returning html, which the browser understands could also be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it

just by sending the correct http headers before the xml part. Come what may the response will always be 200 OK, content type xml and go

here is the python code snippet:

```
try:
    # wait for connection
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    input = conn.recv(4096).strip()
    if input == "TXT":
       conn.send(OutputText(Alerts))
    else:
       HTTPHeader = '''HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml

'''
       HTTPReply = HTTPHeader + OutputXML(Alerts)
       conn.send(HTTPReply)
    # sende data and close connection
    conn.close()
```